# Отображение кода в разных местах на разных разрешениях

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем доброго времени суток!

**Возникла задача отображать код в разных местах на разных разрешениях.**

**Прилагаю картинку, там все наглядно обрисовал**

[image: Вот картинка]
1) Есть есть 3 блока которым нужно назначить порядочность отображения

2) 2 первых блока, которые расположены слева заключены в свой див

3) Далее они обтекаются третьим блоком, который должен идти справа от них

4) (Блок 2) при разрешении меньше 480px, должен сместиться под блок 3

5) Решения с применением "display: none" и другими приемами скрытия не подходят. Нужно, чтобы код отображался “или там” “или там”

6) Можно и визуально блоки переставить, главное чтобы контент в исходном коде не дублировался.

Решение нужно для того, чтобы на мобильной версии не скрывать текст. А переместить его в более удобное место, чтобы сделать акцент на более важной информации. И для СЕО будет полезно. Потому что через скрытие придется дублировать контент для отображения в другом месте. Надеюсь, вы меня поймете. Думаю будет много кому полезно.

К сожалению с программированием не знаком.

Пытался копать в сторону flexbox. Но в моем случае не получается, так как "блок 1" и "блок 2" заключены в общий div.

Comment: добавьте свой код

Comment: Средствами css сделать это невозможно. А на js - не проблема. Обработчик на resize, в нем переместить блок. Ну и при загрузке вызывать тот же обработчик.

Comment: А почему не поменять верстку, убрать лишний `div` и сделать парой строк кода? Иначи, как указал @KAGGDesign, без js не получится, если только у вашего `блока 2` не фиксированная высота.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй flexbox, используй свойство order (порядок следования элементов). Выставляешь блок последним и растягиваешь на всю ширину

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю данное решение с помощю [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
// слушаем событие изменение ширины
$(window).resize(function () {

      // Сам блок, которому будем менять позицию
  var $block2 = $('id или сlass вашего блока'),
      // актуальная ширина окна 
      windowWidth = $(window).width(),
      // Ширина, где нужно применить перемещение блока
      positionChange = 960,
      // Флаг, что бы отработать 1 раз
      flag = false;

  // Если актуальная ширина окна меньше или равна той, где нужно пременить 
  // новую позицию блока - меняем позицию
  // Если нет -  возращаем блок на место
  if( windowWidth <= positionChange && !flag ) {
    $block2
    .clone()
    .end()
    .remove()
    .appendTo('#newPostion');

    var flag = true;
  } else if ( windowWidth <= positionChange && flag ) {
    $block2
    .clone()
    .and()
    .remove()
    .appendTo('#oldPosition');

    var flag = false;
  }

})
```

Документация по методам jQuery

- [Clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [Resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)
- [End](https://api.jquery.com/end/)
- [Remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)
- [AppendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

Но все же рекомендую вам избегать данного подхода, так как это плохая практика. Лудчше посмотрите в сторону рефакторинга **HTML**, и **Flex box**